# How to limit characters in an input text field without maxlength?

Tags: html, forms, field

I am using Input type text in my html page. Now I want to limit the characters based on width of input text field. My input field width is 400px, I want to limit characters upto 95% of my field width.

Limiting maximum characters using maxlength attribute is not fit for my workflow.

Can anyone advice on this please.

Answer (score 0):

- First Calculate the width of text box
- then the font size and then deduce how many characters can be there
  in the 95% of the textbox width
- then add that number as maxlength of the textbox
- For example: Edit the css in the following snippet i.e the font size and width. You will see that max length varies

```js
$(function(){
var noc= .95*parseInt($("#txt").width())/parseInt($("#txt").css("font-size"));
$("#txt").attr("maxlength",parseInt(noc));
$("#maxlengthfound").text(parseInt(noc));
})
```

```css
#txt{width:200px;font-size:10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id='txt'/>
<label id='maxlengthfound'></label>
```